# Pact does not send provider-verification result to pact broker if junit 5 test fails

Tags: java, pact, pact-jvm, pact-java, pact-broker

I have created a REST-service with spring. Now I want to use pact and junit 5 to test the consumer-provider-communication. I have already a running pact-broker (from https://github.com/jaimeniswonger/pact-broker-openshift). The consumer-test works fine and publishes the pacts. The provider-test loads these and trys to verificat them. But the test uploads the results only if the verification is succesfull. I tried running the test with surefire and failsafe.

The code for the test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, properties = "server.port=12223")
@Provider("Provider")
@PactBroker
public class ProviderPactTest {

    @BeforeEach
    void setupTestTarget(PactVerificationContext context) {
        context.setTarget((new HttpsTestTarget("localhost", 12223, "/", true)));
    }

    @TestTemplate
    @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
    void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context) {
        context.verifyInteraction();
    }

    @State({ "state1" })
    public void doNothing() {

    }
}
```

The pact broker properties are defined in the pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <pact.provider.version>${project.version}</pact.provider.version>
            <pact.verifier.publishResults>true</pact.verifier.publishResults>
            <pact.verification.reports>json</pact.verification.reports>
            <pactbroker.tags>TAG</pactbroker.tags>
            <pactbroker.host>pact-broker.url.com</pactbroker.host>
            <pactbroker.port>80</pactbroker.port>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Is it possible to configure the test to notify the pact-broker that a verification failed?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a defect. Can you please raise it in the https://github.com/dius/pact-jvm repository?